# Is there a secret 'special' forge?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I was very first starting to play Skyrim, I stumbled across a blacksmiths forge in the middle of an open field, along with a note saying that something special happened if you use it at night!

I can't remember exactly where it was, does anyone have any more info? My searches aren't turning anything useful up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably meant the lunar forge located in [Silent Moons Camp](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Silent_Moons_Camp), which got it's name from the book [Notes On The Lunar Forge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Notes_On_The_Lunar_Forge).

Comment: Is it different from other forges?

Comment: @aearon No, it's not, though in-game text suggests it should be. There is info claiming it will add an enchant to any weapons Smithed there under a full moon. Someone spent an entire in-game month of nights there and never received the enchant, and there are no stories of it working, so it seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

That's the [Lunar Forge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lunar_Forge#Lunar_Forge). However, it works no differently than other normal forges.

> The Lunar Forge is located at Silent Moons Camp northwest of Whiterun. On a Workbench near the forge is a book called Notes on the Lunar Forge, which suggests that weapons smithed here will convey a "lunar" damage bonus at night when the moons are out. There are several random Lunar weapons around the forge, which do have these properties. However, the Lunar Forge cannot actually be used to create new Lunar weapons. Instead, "Silent Moons Enchant" is an enchantment that can be learned by disenchanting one of the Lunar weapons, and can then be applied to any weapon at any Arcane Enchanter.

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki, Lunar Forge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lunar_Forge#Lunar_Forge)</sup>
The lunar weapons found near the forge have a *[Silent Moons](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Light_Damage)* enchantment. Those don't work too, due to a bug.

> - The Silent Moons Enchant is not actually controlled by phases of the moon. Analysis of the game files reveals the enchantment is designed
>     to deal damage between 9pm and 5am, regardless of lunar phase,
>     weather, or indoor/outdoor location. Note however that due to the bug
>     listed below, the enchantment does not actually deal damage even
>     during allotted times.
> - The Silent Moons Enchant is broken. While targets hit by a Lunar-enchanted weapon will glow as if the effect were working, PC
>     testing via developer console confirms that no extra damage is done.
>     Analysis of the game files reveals this to be due to the enchantment
>     targeting weapon speed and not health.

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki, Light Damage](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Light_Damage)</sup>
This bug can be fixed by the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch (USKP)](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19):

> The health damage effect of the Silent Moons enchantment of Lunar weapons will now work properly.

<sup>[USKP Full changelog](http://afkmods.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Patch%20Version%20History.html)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it doesn't work. However as I read in my book of Skyrim there are 4 weapons with the "Silent Moon" enchant that are found in that area. So if you find one and disenchant it, you will learn the enchant.

Comment: I found 2 lunar swords near the forge. I will try to disenchant it today.

Comment: There are also a couple of other lunar enchanted weapons within the adjacent building

Answer (score -1):

I can say I have used the Silent Moons forge, If you use it at night, It makes silent moon enchanted weapons. They are not really good though. Suckish forge.

Comment: Wrong. Completely!

Answer (score -1):

It works I've used it several times it gives the same enchantment as the items but its very hard ti get the timing right between 11:55pm  to  12:05am during a full moon only

Comment: Wrong. Completely.